# Heruku Deploy Error Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, angular-cli

I am getting this error while I upload `ng` project. When I am localy it works fines. When I upload it to Heruku I get this error.

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  8.1.4
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 8.1.4...
       Downloading and installing node 8.1.4...
       Detected package-lock.json: defaulting npm to version 5.x.x
       Bootstrapping npm 5.x.x (replacing 5.0.3)...
       npm 5.3.0 installed
-----> Restoring cache
       Skipping cache restore (not-found)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

       > orahi-dash-board@0.0.0 preinstall /tmp/build_69fc13367426455c989d318ff32b98f2
       > npm install -g http-server

       /tmp/build_69fc13367426455c989d318ff32b98f2/.heroku/node/bin/http-server -> /tmp/build_69fc13367426455c989d318ff32b98f2/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server
       /tmp/build_69fc13367426455c989d318ff32b98f2/.heroku/node/bin/hs -> /tmp/build_69fc13367426455c989d318ff32b98f2/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server
       + http-server@0.10.0
       added 23 packages in 2.902s

       > orahi-dash-board@0.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_69fc13367426455c989d318ff32b98f2
       > ng build --aot -prod

       sh: 1: ng: not found
       npm ERR! file sh
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno ENOENT
       npm ERR! syscall spawn
       npm ERR! orahi-dash-board@0.0.0 postinstall: `ng build --aot -prod`
       npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
       npm ERR!
       npm ERR! Failed at the orahi-dash-board@0.0.0 postinstall script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-08-02T03_59_17_505Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

What might be the issue?

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.1.4"
  },
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "http-server",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/ *.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "preinstall": "npm install -g http-server",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod",
    "start-dev": "ng serve"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.2",
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "^0.5.0",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.2",
    "angular2-datatable": "0.6.0",
    "angular2-google-maps": "0.17.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "install": "^0.10.1",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "0.8.0",
    "npm": "^5.0.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "zone.js": "0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.6",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0-beta.4",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.1.9",
    "protractor": "5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: Hello, sorry have been offline, I have updated with package.json file.

Comment: Have you tried @Alex's answer?

Comment: Not yet but will be trying it today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular dependencies are added to your `devDependencies` by default. Heroku doesn't install dev dependencies when deploying, so those dependencies need to be moved into the regular `dependencies` section of your `package.json`. See 'Move the @angular/cli Dependency' on this guide: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-cli-deployment-host-your-angular-2-app-on-heroku-3f266f13f352